# Flask app works locally but not on my Azure web app deployment server

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, http, deployment

I working with python 3.9. Where can I see a good exception. Locally I see what I did wrong but on the azure web app web server I cant and only get a 500 Response.

Where can I see more of the exception? I want to know whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying as a Web App to App Service and seeing a 500, then I suggest checking the Log stream. You can also try downloading the Docker logs from "Advanced Tools" and checking the file with the most recent timestamp, that is sometimes easier to follow than Log stream.

You might find this post helpful about debugging Django apps on App Service- the tips are very similar for Flask:
http://blog.pamelafox.org/2023/01/tips-for-debugging-django-app.html